# How to make button enable, when there is value in input date field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one input date field and one button, I want to make the button enable when there is value in input date field. How to make in JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if input has value using `val()`. hope this helps

```js
function check(val)
{
    var btn  = $('.submit')
    if(val)
    {
      btn.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
      btn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
}


$('.date').change(function(e){  // change button disabled property if user provides input        
    check($(this).val());
})

check($('.date').val());       // Function to check input has value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="date" type="date">
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `.on()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='date']").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() != "")
      $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
      $("input[name='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="date" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" disabled="disabled" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

here I initially set attribute `disabled` then remove it once there's input and it's not empty input. If it's empty, I re-add that attribute.

Comment: The OP clearly said date input. So the event must be change